# Nginx: Wordpress installed at /home/me/* instead of /var/www/html/*

Tags: wordpress, nginx

EDIT: All I had to change was the root path in /sites-available/ and change permissions.

So last year I configured my first Nginx server for a Wordpress project. Had the droplet shut off because I was too busy to work on it till now. Long story short...I realized I had Wordpress in my home directory, instead of where I expected it to be /var/www/html/*

Based on my current knowledge, I would use `mv` for this since /var/www/ does not exist.

If I make the directory `/var/www/html/`, move everything Wordpress to that directory, and modify the root path in my config file like so

```
server {

    root /var/www/html;
```

What else has to change?

Tried exactly that and broke it, which I assumed I would. It makes logical sense that that path is referenced elsewhere.

I'm a beginner with Linux and web server config, so pardon my ignorance.

Hoping to learn something, not just be spoon fed the answer

o7

Comment: What does `and broke it` mean, exactly?  What did your `mv` command look like, exactly, where did WP's `index.php` end up?

Comment: From inside `/home/mike/example.com`: `sudo mv example.com/ /var/www/html/`

Comment: The `index.php` I believe you're asking about ended up at `/var/www/html/example.com/public/wp-content/index.php` there's also one in `/var/www/html/example.com/public/index.php` and everywhere else. Looks like everything moved correctly?

`and broke it` means that currently I cannot start nginx and get thrown errors when I do:

`nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/mike/example.com/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

`nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: Well the error clearly tells the problem, right? :-) Your WP setup is not the problem (at least not yet).  You need to either a) create that log file, and make sure the nginx user can write to it; or b) edit your config file and specify a different logfile (making sure it exists and nginx can write to it).  Searching for that error msg turns up plenty of examples here on SO.  Side note: error mgs should be where you *start* tracing the problem.